# Program that calculates the weeks between two dates

Tags: python, algorithm, python-datetime

I want to write a python code that finds Sundays between 1.1.1500 and 31.12.1600 without using any library.

I have printed the dates in the following code.I try to find sunday divide seven but I think is not correct. How can I print the days corresponding to sunday without library?

```
start_date = date(1500, 1, 1)
end_date = date(1600, 12, 31)    # perhaps date.now()

delta = end_date - start_date   # returns timedelta

for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    date_ = start_date + timedelta(days=i)
    #print(date_.weekday())
   # print(date_.day)
    x=date_.day
    y=date_.month
    z = date_.year
   # print(x,y,z)
   # print(type(x))
    if(x%7==0):
        print(x,"sunday")
    else:
        #print("yeter")
```

**

> Output: 7 1 1500 14 1 1500 21 1 1500 ..... ..... To 1600

**

Comment: Why did you tag this question with `c#`?

Comment: "without library" - I assume the datetime library is okay. You may want to include the import to make this a running example.

Comment: The title is a bit misleading: in the question you ask how to find all the Sundays between two dates.

Comment: What about the calender reform?

Comment: @steenslag I am not an expert on this, but calendar reforms should fix months lenght, they don't eliminate weekdays, like "this February will skip a Sunday". Weekdays are fixed AFAIK.